# Bind a controller with a given parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-bootstrap

Using Angular Bootstrap and the $modal service, I create a popup with the following template:

```
<div class="dialog modal-header" ng-show="header.length > 0">
    <h3 compile="header"></h3>
</div>
<div class="dialog modal-body">
    <div compile="bodyTemplate"></div>
</div>
<div class="dialog modal-footer">
    <button ng-repeat="button in buttons"
            ng-show="$parent.$eval(button.showExpression)"
            ng-class="button.class"
            ng-click="onButtonClick(button)">
        <div compile="button.template"/>
    </button>
</div>
```

I built a popup service which help set defaults on the scope, as well as load the bodyTemplate from a templateUrl.

```
// snippit of my popup service
function show(modalOptions, scope) {

    // ....
    // load template from modalOptions.bodyTemplateUrl
    // ....

    var extendedModalOptions = {};
    angular.extend(extendedModalOptions, defaultModelOptions, modalOptions);

    extendedModalOptions.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        angular.extend($scope, scope);

        // .... 
        // add to $scope additional properties from the extendedModalOptions 
        // such as the buttons array and loaded bodyTemplate
        // ....
    }
    $modal.open(extendedModalOptions);
}
```

What I want is to inject a controller to use for the bodyTemplate, like this:

```
<div class="dialog modal-header" ng-show="header.length > 0">
    <h3 compile="header"></h3>
</div>

<!-- Note the addition of ng-controller here -->
<div class="dialog modal-body" ng-controller="bodyController">
    <div compile="bodyTemplate"></div>
</div>

<div class="dialog modal-footer">
    <button ng-repeat="button in buttons"
            ng-show="$parent.$eval(button.showExpression)"
            ng-class="button.class"
            ng-click="onButtonClick(button)">
        <div compile="button.template"/>
    </button>
</div>
```

This could work, however, the $parent of the bodyController scope is now the scope given to the $modal controller. I want to use a different parent.

I'd like to be able to use my popup service like this:

```
// from inside CustomerController
popup.show({
    header: 'Test Popup',
    parentScope: $scope, // the current scope of CustomerController
    bodyTemplateUrl: 'testPopupTemplate.html',
    bodyController: 'TestPopupController as testPopupVM'
});
```

This is where I'm a bit lost. I think my popup service could create the controller like this:

```
$scope.bodyController = $controller(extendedModalOptions.bodyController, {
    $scope: extendedModalOptions.parentScope
});
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that gets me the controller with the correct parent. The problem, however, is that the returned value is the new scope object, and not the constructor function.

According to the angular docs on ng-controller, it can only bind to a constructor function.

How can I add the the body controller to the popup template while using the supplied parent scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to invent your own `$scope` hierarchy while the one provided by Angular is just fine.

By default, modals opened with `$modal` service gets new child scope from `$rootScope`. You can change this by setting a base modal scope explicit, i.e.

```
$modal({
    scope: yourBaseScope
    // other modal options
})
```

Modal will call `yourBaseScope.$new()` upon creation and use it. Therefore, it will have access to all variables and funcitons you define in the `yourBaseScope`.

Read more about modal's scope [in docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from fracz is the better choice, but I want to offer an alternative hack.

Since ng-controller can only bind to a controller function, I built one inside the popup service:

```
$scope.bodyCtrl = function($scope) {
   // HACK: replace the parent with the one from extendedModalOptions
   $scope.$parent = extendedModalOptions.parentScope;

   return $controller(extendedModalOptions.bodyController, {
       $scope: $scope
   });
};
// annotate the controller function so minification does't break injection
$scope.bodyCtrl['$inject'] = ['$scope'];
```

Replacing $parent on a scope manually has code-smell. I hadn't realized you could pass in a $rootScope alternative to $modal.